# Remotely Find Registry Keys in Registry Sub-folders

Tags: remote-access, windows-registry

Via CMD I would like to find out remotely the registry entries for a folder in the registry.

For example.

If I could send a request to a computer to tell me what the keys, d-words, values, etc are in a registry folder...

HKSoftware -> blah blah -> blah blah -> PRIVATE APPLICATION -> SUB FOLDER IN PRIVATE APPLICATION -> Registry Keys in that folder

I hope this question makes sense. Much like another question I asked this is for about 150 machines and was hoping to be able to gather this info quickly.

(These are Windows Boxes)

Thank you.

Comment: I know I can remote access the registry and drill down each time to each computer. I am more looking for a cmd script, etc that can return the info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reg query "\\servername\hklm\SOFTWARE\privateapp"  /s

just a start

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Only thing I noticed is you need two \\ before the server name: 

reg query "\\servername\hklm\SOFTWARE\privateapp" /s

Comment: yea forgot that I need to escape the backslash